# IE8, Mozilla Firefox, not displaying website icons, links, images. WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

After moving to an area my previous internet provider didn't cover and waiting a week for the local internet company to come, they hooked up a new router and after two days, my desktop icons were using different font, and the text boxes were no longer blending in with my background.

I got online to see if I could find a way to fix this, but when I opened IE, it informed me that it was now updated to IE8.  I went to Google and the links for the different search functions were blue and white. After looking for a solution to my desktop (nothing advised worked and since I am one of 3 who use this computer, I dont dare reformat), I tryed going to some of my favorite sites and noticed the same thing. The sites background is gone; the links ( with images) dont appear, yet when I scroll over them, my mouse changes, and I can still click on the link; all the avatars are gone; and none of the customized colors are there: everything is blandly blue and white.  I closed IE and tryed Firefox, with the exact same results.

Real Player and my other web supported browsers are also the same, bland white and blue where colorful sites and images used to be.I have gone through all relevent posts about IE8 and Mozzila not dispaying images, yet the problem is still here. Some posts sounded almost exactly like my problem, yet none of the "solutions" worked for me.  I would greatly appreciate any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an activation issue to me. I've had similar problems with un-activated versions of windows. Is this a new install of windows?

Also, a quick fix could also be to run the repair that came with your copy of windows. You might be missing libraries or have a junk registry. A repair should do the trick.

Comment: Same copy of windows for 5+ years. evidently, one of the not-so-tech-savvy people that use the computer were messing with display properties on the Desktop as a prank, but can't remember what they changed/did.I will try the repair and get back tommorow.

Comment: @SriFree Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question/post a comment to add additional information.